# How can I copy all the hastags in clipboard using typescript which are also in django pagination?

Tags: javascript, django, typescript

Hi I was developing a project in Django. For front-end I was using HTML5 and TypeScript

It looks like this:

[image: Frondend]

My problem is that I have to implement `copyAll` button functionality,
but when I do that, I'm getting only first 10 results. I do not understand how to get all of that 60 results into clipboard.
I tried different codes but none of them worked, I am very new to Typescript.

Nothing helped, there was a stackoverflow post but that also did not help
because my problem is with pagination.

My last attempt:

```
() => {
  let selectAll = document.getElementById("{{ i.id }}") as HTMLInputElement;
  let locationElements=document.getElementsByClassName("mainClass");
  for(let i=0;i<locationElements.length;i++){
    if(selectAll.checked && ((<HTMLInputElement> locationElements[i]).checked==false)){
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your records are not show entirely on the first page, you are not able to select them.

Pagination is good for performance optimized, but not good at all if your records are interacted.

---

There are two approach that I've used before:

### 1. Get all data in the first time, and hide the data that is not belong to the first page.

You can get all your records in the first page, and hide some records that are not in the first page(**but they are still in the dom tree**).

Since records are in the dom tree, you can easily select them.

> **Note:** I don't think this is a good way, since users don't know they select the records they **haven't seen**.

### 2. Create another button says that `select all` and give user a hint.

Create a button and give user a hint like: `select all xxx records` to let user know they are **select real all records** instead of **select all in this page**.

You can see an example in **GMail**.

And more detail [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/43937/how-should-the-select-all-select-when-paginating-elements).